# Calling Document.find with nil is invalid in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, activemerchant

I am using mongodb with active merchant gem in rails4. While use rails cast tutorial #145 Integrating Active Merchant.

## Error

Problem: Calling Document.find with nil is invalid. Summary: Document.find expects the parameters to be 1 or more ids, and will return a single document if 1 id is provided, otherwise an array of documents if multiple ids are provided. Resolution: Most likely this is caused by passing parameters directly through to the find, and the parameter either is not present or the key from which it is accessed is incorrect.

## Order Controller

```
class OrderController < ApplicationController
    include ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations

    def new
        @cart = current_cart

        @order = Order.new
    end

    def success

    end

    def failure

    end

    def create

        @order = current_cart.build_order(params_order)
        @order.ip_address = request.remote_ip
        if @order.save
            if @order.purchase
                render :action => "success"
            else
                render :action => "failure"
            end
        else
            render :action => 'new'
        end

    end

    private

    def current_cart 
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
      cart = Cart.create 
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id 
      cart
   end

   def params_order
    params.require(:order).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :card_type, :card_number, :card_verification, :card_expires_on)  
   end

end
```

## Model

## order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cart
    has_many   :transactions, :class_name => "OrderTransaction"

attr_accessor :card_number, :card_verification

#validate_on_create :validate_card

def purchase
    response = GATEWAY.purchase(price_in_cents, credit_card, purchase_options)
    transactions.create!(:action => "purchase", :amount => price_in_cents, :response => response)
    cart.update_attribute(:purchased_at, Time.now) if response.success?
    response.success?
end

def price_in_cents
    return 100 #(cart.total_price*100).round
end

private

def purchase_options
    {
        :ip => ip_address,
        :billing_address => {
            :name     => "Ryan Bates",
            :address1 => "123 Main St.",
            :city     => "New York",
            :state    => "NY",
            :country  => "US",
            :zip      => "10001"
        }
    }
end

def validate_card
    unless credit_card.valid?
        credit_card.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
            errors.add_to_base message
        end
    end
end

def credit_card
    @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
        :type               => card_type,
        :number             => card_number,
        :verification_value => card_verification,
        :month              => card_expires_on.month,
        :year               => card_expires_on.year,
        :first_name         => first_name,
        :last_name          => last_name
        )
end
```

end

## order_transaction.rb

```
class OrderTransaction
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :order_id, type: Integer
  field :action, type: String
  field :amount, type: Integer
  field :success, type: Mongoid::Boolean
  field :authorization, type: String
  field :message, type: String
  field :params, type: String
end
```

## cart.rb

```
class Cart
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :order
end
```

## Route.rb File

```
get "order/new"
  get "order/success"
  get "order/failure"
  post "order/create", :to => "order#create", as: :orders

  resources :cart do
  resource :order
  end
```

## View

## new.html.haml

```
%br
%br
%h5.text-center 
    = " Order " 
=form_for :order, url:{action: "create"}, html:{class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|
    %div.form-group
        =f.label :first_name, 'First Name' , {:class => 'col-lg-2 control-label'}
        %div.col-lg-3
            =f.text_field :first_name, {:class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "First Name"}
    %div.form-group
        =f.label :last_name, 'Last Name', {:class => 'col-lg-2 control-label'}
        %div.col-lg-3
            =f.text_field :last_name, {:class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "Last Name"}
    %div.form-group
        =f.label :card_type, 'Card Type', {:class => 'col-lg-2 control-label'}
        %div.col-lg-3
            =f.select(:card_type, [["Visa", "visa"], ["MasterCard", "master"], ["Discover", "discover"], ["American Express", "american_express"]], {}, {:class => 'form-control', :placeholder => ""})
    %div.form-group
        =f.label :card_number, 'Card Number', {:class => 'col-lg-2 control-label'}
        %div.col-lg-3
            =f.text_field :card_number, {:class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "378282246310005"}
    %div.form-group
        =f.label :card_verification, 'Card Verification', {:class => 'col-lg-2 control-label'}
        %div.col-lg-3
            =f.text_field :card_verification, {:class => 'form-control', :placeholder => "YES"}
    %div.form-group
        =f.label :card_expires_on, 'Card Expire Date', {:class => 'col-lg-2 control-label'}
        %div.col-lg-3
            =f.date_select :card_expires_on, :discard_day => true, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => (Date.today.year+10), :add_month_numbers => true
    %div.form-group
        %div.col-lg-offset-2.col-lg-10
            =f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary'
```

## Error Occur

**Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind in OrderController#new**
Problem: Calling Document.find with nil is invalid. Summary: Document.find expects the parameters to be 1 or more ids, and will return a single document if 1 id is provided, otherwise an array of documents if multiple ids are provided. Resolution: Most likely this is caused by passing parameters directly through to the find, and the parameter either is not present or the key from which it is accessed is incorrect.
** Your suggestion will helpful. Thanks in advanced**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OrderController#new calls OrderController#current_cart which runs Cart.find(session[:cart_id]).  There's no :cart_id at session start, i.e., session[:cart_id] is nil, and you get the Mongoid::Errors::InvalidFind exception above.  Note that your rescue clause will not rescue that exception as you are rescuing ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound.  You are using Mongoid, not ActiveRecord, and must program accordingly.  Best wishes.